# Evaluate gradient angle at every pixel of a fringe pattern image

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

I am trying to evaluate gradient angle at every pixel location in a fringe pattern.The problem is that there are pixel locations where the gradient goes to zero and at these points the angle calculated is erroneous.I have tried interpolation but it also changes the angle values at pixels where it is correct.I need accurate gradient angle values in the computation of other quantities.Is there any way to obtain the *accurate* gradient angles without having to face the above problem?If not possible,is there a way to do interpolation only in the erroneous region?Or any other way to overcome the problem?
This is my implementation using OpenCV and Python:

```
k1  = np.array([[-1,0,1],[-1,0,1],[-1,0,1]])
dx1 = cv2.filter2D(image,cv2.CV_64F,cv2.flip(k1,-1),(-1,-1))
dy1 = cv2.filter2D(image,cv2.CV_64F,cv2.flip(np.transpose(k1),-1),(-1,-1))
alpha1 =np.arctan2(np.abs(dy1),np.abs(dx1))
```

I am testing it on a simulated circular fringe pattern with added gaussian random noise.I have attached the link for the image without added noise.
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7tJUyO9BT28ZUQ4UFNxQWNhZWc/view?usp=sharing

**Edit 1**:
What I am actually trying to find is the direction of the fringes in the image which is the direction of the tangent at every pixel.So i am finding gradient first and using the fact that tangent is perpendicular to gradient.So if you can suggest an alternative method to find the tangent,it is welcome.

Comment: Mysterious.  If the gradient really goes to zero, and the angle for those points really doesn't get calculated correctly, doesn't that indicate that the arctan2 function in numeric python doesn't actually work?  How can that be true?  Are you *sure* the gradient is exactly zero?  How do you know the exact gradients for each point and what the corresponding angles are?

Comment: Does it work for the image without added noise?

Comment: @PaulCorneliusI am calculating the gradient from x&y derivatives evaluated using the Prewitt kernel.Near fringe extrema,derivative values go very low(not always zero),so gradient is not always zero,but angle calculated here is very different from that in the neighborhood and different for every such extrema.The image of the gradient angles would give a better picture.Even if both partial derivatives are zero,arctan2 just gives angle=0.So arctan2 does not seem to be the source of the problem.

Comment: @JblascoThe problem is not because of random noise but lies in the very nature of a gradient.It persists in images without noise.

Comment: Prewitt, Sobel and others are just approximation of the gradient. I'm aware of few methods to compute more accurate gradients, but I don't know if they would apply here. Could you post (or link) an image with your resulting gradients so it's more clear where your method fails?

Comment: the derivatives seems pretty good to me. [This paper](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B10RxHxW3I92Yzk1YjVlNWItMDZiMi00ZjY4LThjOTctMzY4MGJiODI5MzMy/view) presents a method for accurate tangent estimation. No source code, but it's quite easy to implement. However, as I already pointed out, I don't know if it would apply here, since you need a thin shape for this method to work.